# SQL, Trying to get opposite result

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

So, I was trying to select data but all I can get is opposite of results that I need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  LAND_USE_EVW.OBJECTID
FROM LAND_USE_EVW,
     MUNICIPALITIES_EVW
WHERE LAND_USE_EVW.Shape.STBoundary().STWithin(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.Shape) = 1
```

When I change 1 to 0 it's not working (selecting all rows)

What could I possibly do to get opposite result?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Would `STWithin(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.Shape) != 1` work?

Comment: @jongusmoe I've tried that and changing in value but all did not work.

Comment: What happens when you run SELECT DISTINCT
  LAND_USE_EVW.OBJECTID,  LAND_USE_EVW.Shape.STBoundary().STWithin(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.Shape)
FROM LAND_USE_EVW,
     MUNICIPALITIES_EVW

Comment: @TheTTGGuy some what reason it multiplies result way more then originally has

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the problem is in LAND_USE_EVW.Shape.STBoundary().STWithin(MUNICIPALITIES_EVW.Shape)  or the way you are using it, not in your query.

Comment: @TheTTGGuy thanks, I think I need to try more

Comment: To invert the results in spatial queries, you must use something like ST_Disjoint instead of tweaking the intersects. I don't know enough about your structure to offer an SQL statement, but you should find examples easily in your product help files.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @EmacsUser thanks I'm new to this and trying to figure it out.

Comment: @marc_s I'll take a look into the website you post. Thanks!